# File specifications for HTML folder --> Kindle?

Tags: formatting, kindle

OK, so on the Kindle website there's all about how to go from .doc --> HTML --> kindle. But I write primarily in HTML, which is what Kindle uses in the first place, so it seems silly to convert to HTML --> .doc --> HTML again, then hope that nothing got screwed up in the conversion (and obviously I like the control of putting the file together myself).

Is there somewhere I can read exactly what the structure of a Kindle folder should be? (HTML file + illustrations folder)

I've looked, and all I find is .doc --> HTML --> Kindle.

What tags are allowed, what custom tags (if any) does Kindle need, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wow. There is A LOT of information about formating for the Kindle. In cases where there is so much info, I try to get as close to the source as possible. Therefore, here are links to Amazon's Kindle Direct Publishing. As a side note, since you can email to your Kindle, send yourself the file to see how it looks before finalizing and publishing. Hope this helps you.

Here is a list of [supported tags](https://kdp.amazon.com/self-publishing/help?topicId=A1JPUWCSD6F59O). And [custom tags](https://kdp.amazon.com/self-publishing/help?topicId=A1B8OEIMUN0HFY) are here.